# Oracle JDBC Pool Connection access allocation strategy?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling

When using an Oracle JDBC connection pool, is there a way to control how the connections are handed out? In particular, is there a way to specify using a LIFO strategy? It seems the connections may be handed out in a round robin fashion.

In this scenario:

- max connections in pool are used (10)
- thereafter, only one concurrent connection is ever used, every 5 sec retrieved and returned
- inactivity timeout is set to 60 sec

if a round robin strategy is used, each of the 10 pooled connections will be used within a 60 sec time period. When the inactivity timeout check occurs, every connection will have been active within the last minute, so no connection will be a candidate to be closed. The connection pool will remain with 10 connections, although in reality, only 1 is required. At least that is what I seem to be experiencing. I would like the pool to shrink down to only 1 connection.

Is my understanding of how the driver works correct? Is there a way to control the connection allocation strategy from the pool (LIFO, FIFO, round robin) or would I have to use other pooling mechanisms?

Below is a test (using deprecated apis). In this case, 3 connections were created, and it would only shrink back down to 2, not 1.

EDIT to more closely reflect above description:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1521/SID";
        String user = "user";
        String pwd = "pwd";

        OracleDataSource ocpds;

        ArrayList<Connection> tempConnList = new ArrayList<>();


        try {

            ocpds = new OracleDataSource();
            ocpds.setURL(url);
            ocpds.setUser(user);
            ocpds.setPassword(pwd);

            java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
            prop.setProperty("MinLimit", "1");
            prop.setProperty("MaxLimit", "10");

            prop.setProperty("InactivityTimeout", "60");    //  seconds
            prop.setProperty("AbandonedConnectionTimeout", "60");  //  seconds
            prop.setProperty("PropertyCheckInterval", "60"); // seconds            

            // set DataSource properties
            ocpds.setConnectionCachingEnabled(true);
            ocpds.setConnectionCacheProperties(prop);
            ocpds.setConnectionCacheName("TestCache");


            // Ramp up to max
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                Connection conn = ocpds.getConnection();
                tempConnList.add(conn);
            }

            // Release them all
            for (Connection conn : tempConnList) {
                conn.close();
            }


            // Grab and release one connection at a time
            for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {

                System.out.println(new java.util.Date());

                // Grab and release
                Connection conn = ocpds.getConnection();
                conn.close();

                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    System.err.println("error message: " + ie.getMessage());
                }

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("error message: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            for (Connection conn : tempConnList) {
                if (conn != null) { try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException ignored) {}; }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle support has responded that a round robin method is used for feeding back the connections from the pool. In Oracle JDBC 12  (current version is 11.2.0.3), there will be a property, "UseLIFO", which will allow "last in first out" retrieval:

```
prop.setProperty("UseLIFO", "true");
```

In the example posted in the question, this will let the idle time out to shrink the pool down to a single connection.

Comment: From 11g onwards, Oracle has deprecated OracleImplicitConnectionCache which provides UseLIFO property. Oracle says to use [UniversalConnectionPool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e12265/connect.htm) instead.UCP needs a datasource; where this property is not supported. So moving to 11g or 12c driver using UCP, is it still possible to use this behaviour ?